# Python - functions are not exported from package

Tags: python, unit-testing, package

I have no idea why function from my python package https://github.com/Tazovsky/pyci are not exported:

```
$ python3 setup.py install                                                                                            
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pyci.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pyci.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to pyci.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'pyci.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pyci.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
copying build/lib/.DS_Store -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyci
copying build/lib/pyci/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyci
copying build/lib/pyci/hello.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyci
copying build/lib/pyci/make_custom_yml.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyci
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyci/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyci/hello.py to hello.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pyci/make_custom_yml.py to make_custom_yml.cpython-36.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyci.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyci.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyci.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyci.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyci.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/pyci-0.1.1-py3.6.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing pyci-0.1.1-py3.6.egg
removing '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyci-0.1.1-py3.6.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyci-0.1.1-py3.6.egg
Extracting pyci-0.1.1-py3.6.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
pyci 0.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyci-0.1.1-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for pyci==0.1.1
Finished processing dependencies for pyci==0.1.1
```

Tests output:

```
$ python3 setup.py test
______________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_make_custom_yaml.py _______________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/user/Projects/pyci/tests/test_make_custom_yaml.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_make_custom_yaml.py:3: in <module>
    from pyci import make_custom_yaml
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'make_custom_yaml'
```

Can you help understanding why function `make_custom_yaml` is not found?

Comment: well... the module in pyci is named `make_custom_yml.py` not `make_custom_yaml.py` so the test is trying to import the wrong file.

Comment: also to use the function make_custom_yaml, from the module make_custom_yaml, it needs to be imported as `from pyci.make_custom_yaml import make_custom_yaml`

Comment: See my commit: https://github.com/Tazovsky/pyci/commit/9b26689768cf9ae0e9b88f17806e24426b69880a - still there is no `make_custom_yaml` in `pyci`: `ImportError: cannot import name 'make_custom_yaml'`

Comment: Looks like your latest edit is working past this problem, the first error I encounter now is a `PermissionError` related to removing a file in the temp directory, line 28 in yaml.py